# My update with php and jQuery Ajax its not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this "Read More" link:

```
echo '<p>'.$readNewsResult['content'].'<a class="test" href="#fancybox'.$readNewsResult['id_news'].'">Read More</a></p>';
```

When I click in this link, my goal is to update views column of my news table.

So I have a jQuery where Im passing id of my news, and it is working fine, when I click on "Read more" link I get an alert message saying: "action=update&update=311", where 311 is id of my clicked news.

My jQuery until now:

```
$(function(){
   var read = $('.news');
   read.on('click','.test',function(){
       var updateid = $(this).attr("id");
       var updatedata = "action=update&update="+updateid;
       alert(updatedata);
       $.ajax({
         data:  updatedata,
         beforesend: '',
         error: '',
         success: function(updateR)
         {
             alert(updateR);
         }   
       });
   });
});
```

But now with php, Im trying to get update action and id, and do update on my news table, but its not working, because it seems that I never enter in my switch condition.

I tried to give some "echos" inside my case, and when I click on my "Read more" link my echo never appears.

Do you see where might be the problem??

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
switch($action)
{
    case 'update':
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $updateViews = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE news SET views=:views WHERE id=:id"); 
      $updateViews->bindValue(':views', '1');
      $updateViews->bindValue(':id', $id); 
      $updateViews->execute();
    break;
}
```

Comment: You miss a semicolon ' after the echo code: echo **'**<p>'.$readNewsResult['content'].'<a class="test" href="#fancybox'.$readNewsResult['id_news'].'">Read More</a></p>';

Comment: Thanks, I have that correct on my example, but here I put it wrong thanks for notice. I update now correctly!

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you are trying to work with `$_POST['id']` in your PHP but you are actually creating an URL parameter called `update` which contains the ID in your JavaScript.

The actual issue is that you are lacking an URL argument to your `$.ajax` call.

You are also naming your var `udpdatedata` on this line:

```
   var udpdatedata = "action=update&update="+updateid;
```

but are referencing `updatedata` in the `$.ajax` call:

```
     data:  updatedata,
```

As such your query parameters are never added to the non-existent URL.

An extra one:

```
     sucess: function(updateR)
```

Is actually spelled `success`, note the double c.

Comment: Thanks ikanobori. Your corrections were really helpful! I didnt notice that errors. But my update still dont work! And when I click on "Read  more" link, I get an alert with my php.file code!

Answer (score 1):

Where is your ajax controller url, I mean `url` and also type of call `type`,

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/url/myphpfunction',
     data:  updatedata,
     beforesend: '',
     error: '',
     sucess: function(updateR)
     {
         alert(updateR);
     }   
   });
```

Here is the tutorial http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: Thank you dhana. I read your answer, whole tutorial and made some changes, but Im not seeing why, it isnt work yet!

Comment: @OzzC sorry I am not php developer. But some thing goes wrong in your backend logic. For more bug tracing use chrome developer tool bar.

Answer (score 1):

You had a few things wrong with your ajax function. The first was that you should be passing through an object of values instead of a string. Then you need to specify a method of getting to your script. Then you need to set the URL to your script. See the comments below:

```
$(function(){
    var read = $('.news');
    read.on('click','.test',function(){
        var updateid = $(this).attr("id");
        // pass data as a JS object
        var udpdatedata = {action:'update', update:updateid};
        alert(udpdatedata);
        $.ajax({
            // set the method to post
            type: "POST",
            // the URL to your PHP script
            url: "pathtoscript/script.php"
            data:  updatedata,
            beforesend: '',
            error: '',
            success: function(updateR)
            {
                alert(updateR);
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

Your PHP also had an error, you're passing through 'update', not 'id':

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
switch($action)
{
    case 'update':
        // you're passing through 'update', not 'id'
        $id = $_POST['update'];
        $updateViews = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE news SET views=:views WHERE id=:id"); 
        $updateViews->bindValue(':views', '1');
        $updateViews->bindValue(':id', $id); 
        $updateViews->execute();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Samsquanch, now I understood better how to do this. But its not working yet, when I click in my "Read more" Link Im getting an alert saying: [object Object]

Comment: So now, it seems that Im not also getting id of clicked news.

Comment: You're getting `[object Object]` because what is being returned is some sort of object. Without the rest of your PHP I can't say what it is you're trying to return vs what you're getting. Try using `console.log(updateR)` instead of alert, you might have better luck.